# ASP.NET page redirection list

Tags: asp.net, iis, seo, redirect, response.redirect

For SEO reasons we are about to face a major refactoring for a ASP.NET website. To please SEO engines most of .aspx pages will be renamed. The problem is that these pages are referenced all over the web and we absolutely need to avoid to break these links, nor the SEO ranking boost that comes from these links.

Three questions:

A) Is there a common way to handle this?

B) I'd like to centralize in a C# file or an ASP.NET or IIS config file, a redirection table, something defined like:

```
{ "Page1OldName.aspx", "Page1NewName.aspx" } 
{ "Page2OldName.aspx", "Page2NewName.aspx" } 
{ "Page3OldName.aspx", "Page3NewName.aspx" } 
...
```

I am aware of the `Response.Redirect()` method. I can imagine an ugly way to intercept *page-not-found* error and then use `Response.Redirect()` coupled with the redirection table, but it doesn't look clean. Is there a cleaner way?

C) Do such redirection could/will provoke SEO ranking penalty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use UrlMapping in webconfig.
Test001 is the old url.
Test002 is the new.

```
<system.web>
        <urlMappings>
          <add url="~/test001.aspx" mappedUrl="~/test002.aspx" />
        </urlMappings>
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks Stefano, I am surprised I didn't find this by Googling?! I don't find any resource that tells about the effect of using urlMappings on SEO ranking, maybe because it is transparent for the SEO algorithm?

Comment: UrlMapping running a 301 (moved permanently) on the request. Theoretically it should not affect Google rank. But I'm not completely sure about this.